# Can't read external xml file on jquery

Tags: jquery, html, xml, cordova, phonegap-build

I am developing an app via phonegap and I must read an external xml file which have a lot of important information for my app.

I tried the code below, but I am getting an annoying error. After searching everywhere I did not find any solutions.

The jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://servicos.cptec.inpe.br/XML/cidade/233/condicoesAtuaisUV.xml',
        success: function(data) {
            console.log('ok')
        },
        error: function() {
           console.log('problem')
        }
    });
});
```

The damm error:

**Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://servicos.cptec.inpe.br/XML/cidade/233/condicoesAtuaisUV.xml. (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing).**

I read that it is necessary to enable CORS, but how do I do that?

Thanks for the attention!

Comment: The 3rd party server needs to enable it. So if you do not control that server, you can not do anything with JavaScript.

Comment: you need to add Access-Control-Allow-Origin on server side

Comment: I did that with php, and everything worked just fine. But on jquery, is not working.

Comment: CORS can only be enabled on the server-side, so you need to contact whoever is running the server. Basically by doing so, they're saying "it is okay for a third party to access this resource".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Phonegap, you need to use a white list to access more than one server. The CORS advice you are getting is the correct theme, but not the correct solution - for phonegap.

NOTE: read carefully on this. Many people have been tripped up. There is a difference. As of this month (July 2015), versions after 4.0 and leading edge version will REQUIRE a plugin. (I don't have all the correct details on this, so you'll have to read.)

*Whitelist Guide* 4.0
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/4.0.0/guide_appdev_whitelist_index.md.html

*Whitelist Guide* 3.3
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/guide_appdev_whitelist_index.md.html

Some details here:
http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/which-whitelist-plugin-should-pgb-user-to-use
http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/pgb-support-which-whitelist-function